# schema-registry JSON Schema FULL Compatibility Check

Tags: json, apache-kafka, jsonschema, confluent-schema-registry

Given the following Kafka topic and schema:

```
$kafka-json-schema-console-producer \
>       --broker-list localhost:9092 \
>       --topic topicFull \
>       --property value.schema='{"type":"object","properties":{"a":{"type":"string"}}, "required" : ["a"], "additionalProperties" : true}'
{"a" : "bip"}
```

with `FULL` compatibility:

```
# FULL compatibility
$curl -s -X GET http://localhost:8081/config/topicFull-value
{"error_code":40401,"message":"Subject 'topicFull-value' not found."}
$curl -s -X GET http://localhost:8081/config
{"compatibilityLevel":"FULL"}
```

I checked if adding a required field, `b`, would be compatible:

```
$curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json"  \
>   --data '{"schemaType": "JSON", "schema": "{\"type\":\"object\",\"properties\":{\"a\":{\"type\":\"string\"}, \"b\":{\"type\":\"string\"}},\"required\":[\"a\", \"b\"],\"additionalProperties\":true}"}' \
>   http://localhost:8081/compatibility/subjects/topicFull-value/versions/1 | jq
{
  "is_compatible": false
}
```

The API shows that it's not compatible.

However, I don't understand why adding an optional field, `b`, is not compatible:

```
$curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json"  \
>   --data '{"schemaType": "JSON", "schema": "{\"type\":\"object\",\"properties\":{\"a\":{\"type\":\"string\"}, \"b\":{\"type\":\"string\"}},\"required\":[\"a\"],\"additionalProperties\":true}"}' \
>   http://localhost:8081/compatibility/subjects/topicFull-value/versions/1 | jq
{
  "is_compatible": false
}
```

Can you please explain why adding an optional field fails the compatibility check?

Comment: relevant - https://yokota.blog/2021/03/29/understanding-json-schema-compatibility/

Comment: I believe, though `b` is not required, it would still need a `default` in case the other client is unable to process that field otherwise it wouldn't meet `FULL` Compatibility.